# Connecting to a newly-created socket takes exactly three seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Why is it that when one Java thread starts listening on a port (on 127.0.0.1) and another thread connects to that port, the `connect()` call takes exactly 3 seconds, even if the threads are sufficiently synchronized?

I.e., why is it that my test program results in an output of

```
Server: accepting...
Client: connecting...
Server: accepted. Millis: 3008
Client: connected. Millis: 3008
```

most of the time?

The test was run on a Windows 7 PC using both Java 1.6 and 1.8 with the same result. I assume that, although I use a CountDownLatch for synchronization, that I run into a race condition between `bind()` and `connect()`. There seems to exist a time window immediately after `bind()` (which is called in the server socket's constructor) in which the port is not yet *really* bound so that `connect()` runs into an error and retries.

But this is just my interpretation. Here is the code:

```
public class ConnectAccept
{

    private static final int PORT = 46583;
    private static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void runClient() throws Exception
    {
        latch.await();
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        System.out.println("Client: connecting...");
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", PORT));
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Client: connected. Millis: " + (t1 - t0));
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void runServer() throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        latch.countDown();
        System.out.println("Server: accepting...");
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        serverSocket.accept();
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Server: accepted. Millis: " + (t1 - t0));
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    runClient();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        runServer();
    }

}
```

Comment: When I run your code in my eclipse, it gives me values between 6 and 9 millis.

Comment: Your problem might be that the client tries to connect *before* the server starts listening. The clients connect request will time out (3 seconds) and auto-retry. This is because the client may run from `await()` to `connect()`, before the server runs from `countDown()` to `accept()`. In real life, this will be a non-issue, since the client won't actually be notified to try connecting that quickly. To confirm, try adding a 100ms delay to client, between `await()` and `connect()`.

Comment: The time window in the server is around `accept()`, not around `bind()`.

Comment: When I tried inserting `Thread.sleep(500)` before `latch.countDown()` (i.e., between `bind()` and `connect()`), the problem disappeared _most of the time_. This means that it was indeed `bind()` that didn't work synchronously. This behavior seems to have been caused by Check Point VPN being installed on my machine.

Comment: No, it means your client was connecting before the socket was listening, and engaging in retries. `bind()` doesn't take three seconds, but connect retries do,

Comment: @EJP exactly, but I would assume the socket to be listening immediately after `bind()` (which is called from the ServerSocket's constructor). Thus, both `connect()` and `accept()` should have returned immediately without retry delay. Even though I used proper synchronization in the example, both blocked for three seconds. This behavior stopped immediately when I uninstalled Check Point VPN, so I think what I observed was an unfortunate side-effect of that software.

Answer (score -1):

This problem disappeared completely and reliably after I uninstalled *Check Point VPN*, which seems to have caused the side effect of making `bind()` asynchronous.